# Bad config line for ssh key while performing git operations (like clone)

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys

I'm unable to perform git operations like `git clone` or even `git status`. I'm able to connect using ssh to github so the issue seems git specific?

I was unable to find much logs to try to pin point the issue what else can I try? Any pointers to debug are appreciated. TIA.

```
$ GIT_TRACE=true git clone git@github.com:my_id/repo1.git
22:54:11.817381 git.c:462               trace: built-in: git clone git@github.com:my_id/repo1.git
Cloning into 'repo1'...
fatal: bad config line 1 in file ~/.ssh/my_github_key

$ ssh -vvv -i ~/.ssh/my_github_key -T git@github.com
.....
Hi my_id! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
.....

$ git --version
git version 2.41.0
```

Note: The error message mentions **key file** and not the config as many of the other questions here.

Comment: `git` is trying to read `~/.ssh/my_github_key` as a git config file.  Your `ssh` command illustrates that `~/.ssh/my_github_key`  is a working ssh key, so it certainly is *not* a valid git config file.  You need to find out *why* `git` is trying to read it as a git config file by looking through your global git config options.  https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration may help you find the setting you need to fix

Comment: So, git is trying to read the key file as config, makes sense. I'll go through the docs. I might have made some mistake while setting up the machine in a hurry.

Comment: `git config --list --show-origin | grep -F my_github_key`